# Avoid linking params during authentication not working in cronofy

Tags: cronofy

I want to create a new account every time user authenticates via cronofy, my link is as below

```
https://app.cronofy.com/oauth/authorize?
response_type=code&
**avoid_linking=true**&
client_id={clinet_id}&
redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&
scope={scope}
```

I saw in there documentation for that we need to pass "avoid_linking" params but still every account is created as a profile in previously created account

**How to make it work so that every new user is created as a separate account with a new subId**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Karl at Cronofy Support here. Once the accounts are linked, we need to unlink them before avoid_linking works as you expect.

Could you please email support@cronofy.com with the email address for the accounts you'd like unlinking, and we will get that sorted for you?

Many thanks
Karl